# Задача на работу со стэком/Работа со списками

Tags: python, python-3.x

Уже несколько дней мучаюсь над задачей со степика, кажется, что решение совсем близко, но никак не могу понять, в чём причина.
Условие:
Напишите программу, которая будет эмулировать функциональность стека. Вам на вход будут поступать четыре команды:

add <число> – добавить в стек число,(add 3 например)
pop – удалить из стека число и напечатать его,
head – вывести текущий элемент стека,
close – завершить программу,

```
number=[]
while True:
   n = input()
   
     n = input().split()
  
  if n!='close'and len(n)==2:  
     
      a = v[0]
      b = v[-1]

       if a== "add":
           number.append(b)


       if a== "head":
               print(number)
       elif a== "pop":
               numb= number.pop()
               print(numb)
   if n=='close':
                exit(0)

print(number)
```

ВВОД
add 5,
add 10,
head,
pop,
add 7,
add 9,
pop,
pop,
head,
close,
ВЫВОД
10,
10,
9,
7,
5,
Результат Empty, кажется, не вижу очевидного, подскажите

Comment: Что проверяет условие `len(n)==2`?

Comment: Если пользователь ввёл значение по типу 'add 5', но в коде оно выглядело так while True:
   n = input().split()
   
   if n!='close'and len(n)==2:  
      
       a = v[0]
       b = v[-1]
просто видимо правящаяся версия перенеслась, но всё равно что-то не то

Comment: Словами скажите, что вы хотите проверить условием `len(n)==2`? "Я хочу проверить что ...".

Comment: хочу проверить, что пользователь вводит два слова, а не одно

Comment: `len(n)` измеряет длину строки в символах, не в словах. Поэтому у вас не работает условие.

Comment: Я вижу вы поправили код. Теперь условие работает. Зато сломалось условие `n!='close'`.

Comment: Кроме того вы выбрасываете половину строк. Вы умеете пользоваться отладчиком в вашей среде программирования?

Comment: пользуюсь VS, а там он не работает, поэтому пишу прямо на степике

Comment: Скачайте `PyCharm Community` и научитесь пользоваться отладчиком. То что у вас нет нужного инструментария под рукой - не оправдание. Вы учите язык, так учите правильно.

Comment: ну..спасибо за помощь

Comment: В части кода вы обращаетесь с переменной `n` как если бы она была списком. В части кода - как если бы она была строкой. Я могу показать вам что и как надо исправить, в этом мало толку. Вам нужно научиться читать код. Для этого надо уметь смотреть на код с точки зрения компьютера. Лучше всего для этого поработать с отладчиком, пока не появится навык. Без обид.

Comment: Хорошо,буду пробовать

Answer (score 1):

У вас одна двуместная операция `add` и три одноместные. Поэтому проверка `len(n)==2` для трех команд неправильна, более логично сделать эту проверку только для обработки `add`, а то и вовсе убрать, если проверять `v[0]`.

Кроме того, `head` должно выводить только последний элемент списка, а не весь список.

И нужно предусмотреть случай обращения к пустому списку для `pop` и `head`. А как именно это обрабатывать - должно быть в задании.

Answer (score 0):

number=[]

while True:
n = input()

```
if n!='close':
    v = n.split()
    a = v[0]
    b = v[-1]
    if a== "add":
        number.append(b)
    if a== "head":
           print(number[-1])
    elif a== "pop":
        numb= number.pop()
        print(numb)
if n=='close':
            exit(0)
```

print(number)

Проблема была просто в сместившихся блоках,(раньше даже с head  print(number[-1]) не работало) алгоритм, по сути,верный

Comment: Зачем нужно  `b = v[-1] ` в большинстве случаев? Почему обработка close выполняется иначе?